# ERROR: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'methodName'

Tags: c#

I need to pass different objects instantiated from different classes which they have a function with same name, and I would like to call that function.

For example:

```
Class1 object1;
Class2 object2;
Class3 object3;

Object object = object1;
object1->functionname();

Object object = object2;
object2->functionname();

Object object = object3;
object3->functionname();
```

this is not possible in c#...

In php it's pretty simple you can just do it with object like the sample above but in c# i get this error:  **ERROR: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'methodName'**

I though it's legal to call any method name on a object object! since it doesn't know what is really inside.

How can I do that?

Comment: PHP is dynamically (duck) typed, C# is statically typed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface that both classes implement.
Then pass the object via the type of your interface to your function:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    void Speak();
}

class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public void Speak()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meow!");
    }
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void Speak()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Woof!");
    }
}


static class Program
{

    static void SpeakPlease(IAnimal animal)
    {
        animal.Speak();
    }
 //...
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I though it's legal to call any method name on a object object! since it doesn't know what is really inside.

No, it's **illegal** to call any method apart from the ones defined on `Object` itself. Perhaps you are thinking of `dynamic`?

But instead I think you should create a common interface.

```
interface IProcessable
{
    void Process();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

c# is statically typed: it looks up method names when the code is compiled, not when it is run. `object` doesn't have that method name, so you can't expect to call that function.